# how many minimum possible co prime grouping upto $n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

Suppose $n=5$. One co-prime grouping can be $\{(1,2),(3,4,5)\}$.

There can be any other combination, but the number of groups will be always $2$, i.e. $(1,2)$ and $(3,4,5)$.

Number of elements in a group can be minimum $2$.

---

Huge edit, so set off for inspection by OP.

Let $n$ be a positive integer.  We say "$n$ makes us happy" when there is a partition of the integers $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ into two subsets, $p_1, p_2$ such that for all $x,y \in p_1$ with $x \neq y$, $\gcd(x,y) =1$, and similarly for distinct pairs of numbers in $p_2$.

What is the largest $n$ that makes us happy?

Comment: This is not clear.  Please edit your post for clarity.  In your example, for instance, why wouldn't $\{(1,4),(2,3,5)\}$ be a valid "pair"? or $\{(2,3), (1,4,5)\}$?

Comment: The edit didn't clarify anything.  $(3,4,5)$ is not a pair, for example.

Comment: I have proposed a rewrite of your question as an edit to your question.  I may have changed your meaning, so you should check carefully before using any of my proposed changes.

Comment: its was grouping not pairs .  suppose    n=5   combination first {(1,2),(3,4,5)}              
 combination second {(2,5),(1,3,4)}   similarly there can be other combinations but  we just have to calculate number of such groups formed in one of above combination with with the constraints that each group has min 2 elements.

Comment: If I have understood you (dar from clear), then for $n=8$ the answer is $4$, and $\{(1,2,3,5,7),(4),(6),(8)\}$ is an example.  Indeed, the answer in general is $\big \lfloor \frac n2\big \rfloor$ since you need at least one subset for each even number $≤n$.

Comment: thanks sir i understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any such partition cannot have more than one even number in $p_1$ or in $p_2$, otherwise any two such even numbers are not coprime.  So there are at most two even numbers in $\{1,2,\dots n\}$, which forces $n < 6$.  You have given an example with $n = 5$, so $5$ is the largest number that makes us happy.

Comment: thanks sir i understood.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear.  I am interpreting it as asking:  for each $n\in \mathbb n$ let $\Psi(n)$ denote the minimal number of subsets in a partition of $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ into disjoint subsets where the disjoint subsets are required to consist of relatively prime elements.

With my interpretation, we have $$\Psi(n)=\Big \lfloor \frac n2\Big \rfloor$$

To see that note that we need at least one subset for each even number.  Thus $\Psi(n)≥\Big \lfloor \frac n2\Big \rfloor$

to get the opposite inequality, consider an odd prime $p$ and note that there are fewer than $\Big \lfloor \frac n2\Big \rfloor$ multiples of $p$ which are $≤n$, hence for each $p$ we can put $0$ or $1$ multiple of $p$ in each of the $\Big \lfloor \frac n2\Big \rfloor$ subsets.  And we are done.